# Defining a function to add a black filled oval in Python with PyGraphics

Tags: python, pygraphics

in python I am trying to create a picture with 20 by 20 pixels. Then define a function to add a black 16 by 16 oval at position (0, 0). But I am doing something wrong which I can't put my finger on. Please help. Thanks.

```
import media

pic=media.create_picture(20,20)

def copy_right(pic):
    media.add_oval_filled(pic,0,0,16,16,"black")
    return media.show(pic)

copy_right(pic)
```

Comment: Thanks, i was editing it to put it the right way, but you did it ahead. Thanks

Comment: Looks like Toronto CSC homework ([PyGraphics](http://code.google.com/p/pygraphics/) is used there). Problem is insufficiently defined, and expected and occurring results even less so. What is not as expected, what was expected, and what do you get?

Comment: Yeah, its is an exercise from UTSG,CS. . I don't understand by what you said when you said " media is certainly not a standard Python module" and I know an oval with height and wide equal would be circle. but i when i called help on media and looked it up it said "add_oval_filled(pic, x, y, w, h, col)
        Draw a filled oval of Color col, width w, and height h on Picture pic.
        The upper left corner of the oval is at (x, y)."                 I am really lost at what your saying. Thanks.

Comment: Pardon the confusion, that was from before I noticed the mention of PyGraphics (without that, I did not know where `media` came from). I have found the documentation, but you're still not saying anything about what the program does (i.e. how it goes wrong), and presumably the course involves some guidance too. I'm not even from the same continent, let alone the same university.
A guess is it might involve colors being a class of its own (see media.create_color()) which might not have a way to look up names.

Comment: CORRECTION: and I know an oval with height and wide equal would be circle. but i was told "a black 16 by 16 oval at position (0, 0)" and by the way how did you know it was a homework/exercise  form UofT?

Comment: wait, when your say " but you're still not saying anything about what the program does", are you asking what I want the function i'm trying to write, to do?...

Comment: No, I'm asking what the symptoms are. If you're doing "something wrong", somewhere along the line you've determined the program is incorrect; show us what happens, and how it's wrong. That's the beginnings of finding why.

Comment: I keep getting this error message:                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 6, in copy_right
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphics\media.py", line 133, in add_oval_filled
    pic.add_oval_filled(col, x, y, w, h)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphics\picture.py", line 333, in add_oval_filled
    draw.ellipse([x, y, x + w, y + h], outline=tuple(col.get_rgb()),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_rgb'

Comment: I finally go it, since black is from the media module, i had to put media.black instead of black. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback (which should be put in a listing block in the question) shows a type error, where PyGraphics expects something with a `get_rgb()` method, but got a string. You need to replace "black" in your code with a Color object from PyGraphics.

Comment: ummm.... I already tried that and it said:                  "NameError: global name 'black' is not defined"

Comment: import media

def copy_right():
    pic=media.create_picture(20,20)
    media.add_oval(pic,0,0,16,16,media.black)
    media.add_text(pic,6,3,"C",media.black)    
    return pic
THOUGHT I'LL JUST PUT IT UP.